# Why is no value passed for parameter 'imageAnalyzer'?

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection, method-call

I'm currently working on an object detection application for Android. The application uses a live camera preview from a mobile device to detect objects and draw a box around it. However, I'm facing some impediments to completing this project. The following code ends with a closing parenthesis with a red squiggly underline, with the error that its a `No value passed for parameter 'imageAnalyzer'`.

```
val element = DrawGraphic(context = context,
                                rect = detectedObjects.boundingBox,
                                text = detectedObjects.labels.firstOrNull()?. text ?: "Undefined") //<-this parenthesis
```

However, the IDE also provides the suggestion that I could `Create function 'DrawGraphic'`. The thing is, DrawGraphic.kt is another class within this application that I'm trying to call. It provides the graphic overlay that will display a box around the detected object. I will provide the code for both classes (MainActivity & DrawGraphic) down below. My question is focused on why this is happening; and more imporantly, how would I resolve it?

Any additional information will be provided upon request.

### MainActivity.kt

```
typealias LumaListener = (luma:Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private class LuminosityAnalyzer(private val listener: LumaListener) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            rewind() //Rewind the buffer to zero
            val data = ByteArray(remaining())
            get(data) //Copy the buffer into byte array
            return data //Return the byte array
        }

        override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
            val luma = pixels.average()

            listener(luma)

            image.close()
        }
    }

    class YourImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

        @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
        override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
            Log.d("TAG", "THIS IS WORKIN!!!!!!!")
            val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

                val localModel = LocalModel.Builder()
                        .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite")
                        .build()

                val customObjectDetectorOptions =
                        CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                                .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                                .enableClassification()
                                .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                                .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                                .build()

                val objectDetector =
                        ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions)


                //val context = binding.root.context

                objectDetector
                        .process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess, ITS WORKING!!!!!!")
                            for (detectedObjects in it) {

                                if (binding.parentLayout.childCount > 1) binding.parentLayout.removeViewAt(1)

                                val context = binding.root.context

                                val element = DrawGraphic(context = context,
                                rect = detectedObjects.boundingBox,
                                text = detectedObjects.labels.firstOrNull()?. text ?: "Undefined")

                                binding.parentLayout.addView(element)
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("TAG", e.localizedMessage) }
                        .addOnCompleteListener { it -> imageProxy.close() }
            }
        }

    }

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outPutDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        //Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }
        outPutDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        val preview = (findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.PreviewView))

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider:ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also { it.setSurfaceProvider(preview.surfaceProvider) }

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "Average Luminosity: $luma")
                        })
                    }

            val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
            imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(executor, YourImageAnalyzer())

            try {
                //unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                //Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                "Permissions not granted by user",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### DrawGraphic.kt

```
class DrawGraphic(context: Context, imageAnalyzer: var rect: Rect, var text: String): View(context) {

    lateinit var boxColor: Paint
    lateinit var textColor: Paint

    init {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        boxColor = Paint()
        boxColor.color = Color.WHITE
        boxColor.strokeWidth = 10f
        boxColor.style = Paint.Style.STROKE

        textColor = Paint()
        textColor.color = Color.WHITE
        textColor.textSize = 50f
        textColor.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawText(text, rect.centerX().toFloat(), rect.centerY().toFloat(), textColor)
        canvas?.drawRect(rect.left.toFloat(), rect.top.toFloat(), rect.right.toFloat(), rect.bottom.toFloat(), boxColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: class DrawGraphic(context: Context, imageAnalyzer: var rect: Rect, var text: String): View(context) {
 ===> class DrawGraphic(context: Context, var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis, var rect: Rect, var text: String): View(context) {

Comment: @NhânKhuấtVăn I have made this change to the method signature to no avail. It does nothing to ail the problem unfortunately. Any next steps?